# length of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a nested configuration dictionary and I need a function to test whether  a key exists (up to any level). I came up with this simple function but it fails because on the last item, I end up with just a string and the the len(test) returns the length of the string item. Do I have to change the way I assign all but the first element of test?

```py
conf = {'a':{'b':{'c': [1,2,3]}}}
def has_conf_value(*key_path):
  remaining = conf
  test = key_path
  while len(test) > 1:
    if test[0] in remaining:
      remaining = remaining[test[0]]
      test = test[-1]
    else:
      return False
  return test[0] in remaining

has_conf_value('a','b','c')
```

I expect True

Comment: Do you just want to check if all keys passed as argument are available in dictionary?

Comment: The line `test = test[-1]` is wrong. Should have been `test = test[1:]`.

Comment: Thanks! I checked the [-1] with a list of length two which had the expected result.. bad example on my behalf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do it recursively

```
def has_conf_value(conf, *key_path):
    assert len(key_path) > 0
    if len(key_path) == 1:
        return key_path[0] in conf
    if key_path[0] in conf:
        return has_conf_value(conf[key_path[0]], *key_path[1:])
    return False
```

or

```
def has_conf_value(conf, *key_path):
    assert len(key_path) > 0
    if len(key_path) == 1:
        return key_path[0] in conf
    return has_conf_value(conf[key_path[0]], *key_path[1:]) if key_path[0] in conf else False
```

to be briefer. But all you need to change in your original implementation if you want to keep it as similar to the code you currently have is change

```
test = test[-1]
```

to

```
test = test[1:]
```

or else you are throwing away most of your list. See ShioT's comment below for a more descriptive explanation of *why* `test[-1]` is wrong.

Comment: I feel that "or else you are throwing away most of your list" is not direct enough as the reason. It not only throws away everything but the last thing, it also doesn't even retain the type of list. It turns `[1, 2, 3, 4]` into just `4`, and not `[4]`, which would have been "better" in some limited case.